# Есть ли способ найти список доменов, перенапрявляющих запросы на определённый домен?

Tags: dns, domain

**Дано:**

Некий домен, например `example.com`. Домен чужой, доступа к нему нет.

**Задача:**

Найти все домены, которые перенаправляют на заданный домен. Все домены также чужие, доступа к ним нет. Нужно получить просто список доменов, например `example1.com`, `example2.net` etc.

**Вопрос:**

Возможно ли это? Может где-то есть какие-то списки доменов или можно какими-то командами это выяснить или есть сайты, предоставляющие подобную информацию?

Comment: Что-то я сильно подозреваю, что это невозможно без банального перебора всех существующих доменов (как получить их список - это отдельный вопрос). В конце концов, ничего не мешает мне через 10 минут развернуть на домашнем компьютере, доступном по адресу `<что-нибудь>.no-ip.org` сервис, который все, что будет делать - это редиректить на этот самый example.com. Но узнать об этом можно будет, только непосредственно попытавшись открыть это мое `<что-нибудь>.no-ip.org`.

Comment: Нельзя =) (15 символов)

Comment: Эх, жаль( Спасибо за ответы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Команд таких нет.

Есть много некоммерческих и коммерческих проектов, которые парсят регистраторов, делают обходы сайтов собирая инфу о установленном ПО -- возможно, что у кого-то такая услуга и есть в платных. (В бесплатных не видел, но как-то и не обращал внимания) Думаю, это будет именно в платных, потому что иногда видел подобную услугу "история домена" (когда что и как менялось).

Но это будет только на текущий момент времени, с какой-то степенью точности.

Comment: Я подозревал что так оно и есть( Спасибо! =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб bing.com по запросу `IP:1.1.1.1` ищет все домены, которые ему известны и которые привели на данный ip, это может несколько помочь с поиском, но конечно не даст исчерпывающего ответа

Comment: @Mike, интересная фича, но мне не очень помогла - сайты целевые на движке `wikidot` и от этого выдача мало полезна(